# Finding the second highest value instead of the max value "-1"

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm creating a R sweave file that will compile a pdf report of testing data from a piece of software. The data is mostly pulled from a SQL server table that looks something like this:

```
| FileName | Version | Category | Value |         Date        | TestNum |
|:--------:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:-------------------:|:-------:|
| File1    | 1.0.12  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.12  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.12  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.17  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File1    | 1.0.17  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File1    | 1.0.17  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File2    | 1.0.17  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File2    | 1.0.17  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File2    | 1.0.17  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 3       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
```

I use the TestNum column to make it easier to incrementally count the versions since they are strings. So in my R script, I had a section that was supposed to find the latest version and the one right before that.

```
vLatest <- unique(df[df[,"TestNum"] == max(df$TestNum), "Version"])
vPrevious <- unique(df[df[,"TestNum"] == max(df$TestNum)-1, "Version"])
```

However, there are times when one version of the software was extremely buggy and crashes for every test. This isn't extremely useful to see in the charts so I just add a line in the SQL database that I use to filter it out, then the R dataframe ends up looking like this:

```
| FileName | Version | Category | Value |         Date        | TestNum |
|:--------:|:-------:|:--------:|:-----:|:-------------------:|:-------:|
| File1    | 1.0.12  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.12  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.12  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File2    | 1.0.12  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 1       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.15  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File2    | 1.0.15  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 2       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | Run Time | 74    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | Totals   | 468   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File1    | 1.0.21  | DB Size  | 589   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | Run Time | 81    | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | Totals   | 351   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
| File2    | 1.0.21  | DB Size  | 625   | 2016-10-01 12:00:00 | 4       |
```

But then `vPrevious` is still looking for `TestNum == 3` and so the script breaks. Is there a way that I could look up the second highest value instead?

**EDIT**: By suggestion, here's the what the query looks like that I use to create the dataframe.

```
df <- sqlQuery(db, "select FileName, Version, Category, Value, Date, TestNum 
               from Table where Comments != 'Do Not Include in R Chart'",
               stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: vPrevious <- unique(df[df[,"TestNum"] == sort(unique(df$TestNum), T)[2], "Version"])

Comment: @dww That was the solution I was looking for thanks!

Comment: @David I've updated with Sql according to your query. While you have an option of achieving the same result in Sql and R could you take a moment to compare results and performance? Might give some interesting insights... Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `dense_rank` with `order by TestNum`

The code snippet below gives an example of it's usage.

```
select c.*
from (
    select *,dense_rank() over (order by [object_id] desc) as [row_number]
    from sys.columns
    ) c
where c.[row_number] in (1,2)
```

If you can add your Sql query to the question then it might help in giving a more targeted response.

**EDIT:**

Tailored to op's original query;

```
select FileName, Version, Category, Value, Date, TestNum
from (
    select FileName, Version, Category, Value, Date, TestNum
         , dense_rank() over (order by [TestNum] desc) as [row_number]
    from Table
    where Comments != 'Do Not Include in R Chart'
    ) t
where t.[row_number] in (1,2)
```

Comment: Why the downvote to this answer? A ranking function is *exactly* what is needed to retrieve the 2nd, 3rd best value according to some criteria.